# Hibernate + Maven + MySQL Connector

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, maven, dependencies

I have a little bit of a problem here.

When I started a new project in Eclipse for instance, I add a new dependency with Maven to manage the MySQL connector dependency.

But when I configure a new Driver Definition, it says that it is unable to locate JAR/zip file of the driver definition mysql-connector-java. But as long as I understand it is manage by Maven so it should be anywhere on the Eclipse project right? If I have to downloaded manually and save it on my local drive what is the use of manage that dependency with Maven?

Comment: Dependencies are managed by pom.xml file in maven project. So there's no need to add jar file externally. You can put maven dependency in pom.xml to include mysql connector

Comment: That's what I do, add the maven dependency in the pom.xml. But when I try to create a new Driver Definition to connect to my MySQL database Eclilpse says that there is no mysql-connector-java JAR

Comment: check in your local maven repository for mysql connector jar  whether it is available or not.

Comment: Have you update maven project after building? (Shortcut Alt+F5)

Comment: Thanks @zombie I totally forgot about the local maven repository. The file it's there

Comment: @a.ras2002 As you are using maven, the dependency automatically get downloaded into your local .m2 repository from the central maven repository, so if it is not automatically downloaded then you can use mvn compile to download compile time dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about maven, but I use Gradle... In these cases, what happens, there is a .gradle folder available.

We normally delete the `...users/.gradle/files/cache/{project}` contents from the same path and do the gradle refresh. You can try with the same.